# How does Excel handle scope when passing parameters to nested sub procedures

Tags: macos, excel, vba

I´m calling this sub procedure from another sub procedure. When I refactored this code out of the main procedure, the variables no longer register in my watch window nor does the code execute correctly. However, I can hover my cursor over myArray(x,y) when debuggging and it shows the value loading into the array. I imagine I might have a problem with scope, any insights?

```
Public Sub calcPriceCycles(ws As Worksheet, thisRow As Integer)
Dim k As Integer
Dim myArray(0 To 10, 0 To 1) As Long

            'ArraySum = 0
            For k = 0 To 10
                If thisRow >= 12 Then 'calculate up to row 12 due to array size
                    myArray(k, 0) = ws.Cells(thisRow - k, 5)
                    myArray(k, 1) = thisRow - k
                End If
            Next k

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have coded this routine, `myArray` is not visible outside the sub.  The array is local.  To make `myArray` visible you have three options:

1. pass the array back out through the header
2. use a function rather than a sub
3. make the scope of `myArray` more global by moving the `Dim` outside the sub

Comment: @GarysStudent, Would you elaborate on option1 - passing the array back out through the header?